# Defaulting intermediate type variables

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-level-computation, data-kinds, singleton-type

I'd like to represent a list of `(before, during, after)` pairs such that `all (\(_, _, after), (before, _, _) -> after == before) $ zip xs (tail xs)`; in other words, such that neighbouring pairs match on their ends. The end goal is to extract a collapsed list of `(before, [(during, after)]`.

We can implement that easily using a [`Star`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Star.agda)-like structure to enforce matching ends:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons

data Step a (before :: ending) (after :: ending) where
    Step :: (SingI before, SingI after) => a -> Step a before after

infixr 5 :>
data Steps a (first :: ending) where
    Nil :: Steps a first
    (:>) :: Step a before after -> Steps a after -> Steps a before

before :: forall ending a (before :: ending) (after :: ending). (SingKind ending) => Step a before after -> Demote ending
before Step{} = FromSing (sing @before)

after :: forall ending a (before :: ending) (after :: ending). (SingKind ending) => Step a before after -> Demote ending
after Step{} = FromSing (sing @after)

collapse :: forall ending a (first :: ending). (SingKind ending) => Steps a first -> (Maybe (Demote ending), [(a, Demote ending)])
collapse Nil = (Nothing, [])
collapse xs@(x :> _) = (Just $ before x, go xs)
  where
    go :: Steps a whatever -> [(a, Demote ending)]
    go Nil = []
    go (s@(Step x) :> xs) = (x, after s) : go xs
```

An example of usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, PatternSynonyms, TypeFamilies, StandaloneDeriving #-}
import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
  data Ending = A | B | C
  |])
deriving instance Show Ending

foo :: Steps Int A
foo =
    Step @A @B 1 :>
    Step @B @C 2 :>
    Nil
```

> ```
> > collapse foo
> (Just A,[(1,B),(2,C)])
> ```

So far so good.

But now, let's say some of those `Step`s don't really care about their endings. While we can let type inference fill them in where they are unambiguous, e.g.

```
example1 :: Steps Int A
example1 =
    Step 1 :>
    Step @B @C 2 :>
    Nil
```

But this breaks down if there are not enough constraints to resolve ambiguity, e.g. this fails:

```
example2 :: Steps Int A
example2 =
    Step 1 :>
    Step 2 :>
    Step @B @C 3 :>
    Nil
```

> Ambiguous type variable `after0` arising from a use of `Step`
>        prevents the constraint `(SingI after0)` from being solved.

It is understandable that this can't be made to work; for example, there would be no place from which we can pull the `ending` we put in the `collapse`d list.

We can, instead, make "not caring" explicit by using a `Maybe ending` on both sides:

```
data Step a (before :: Maybe ending) (after :: Maybe ending) where
    Step :: (SingI before, SingI after) => a -> Step a before after

data Steps a (first :: Maybe ending) where
    Nil :: Steps a first
    (:>) :: Step a before after -> Steps a after -> Steps a before
infixr 5 :>

before :: forall ending a (before :: Maybe ending) (after :: Maybe ending). (SingKind ending) => Step a before after -> Maybe (Demote ending)
before Step{} = FromSing (sing @before)

after :: forall ending a (before :: Maybe ending) (after :: Maybe ending). (SingKind ending) => Step a before after -> Maybe (Demote ending)
after Step{} = FromSing (sing @after)

collapse :: forall ending a (first :: Maybe ending) . (SingKind ending) => Steps a first -> (Maybe (Demote ending), [(a, Maybe (Demote ending))])
collapse Nil = (Nothing, [])
collapse xs@(x :> _) = (before x, go xs)
  where
    go :: Steps a whatever -> [(a, Maybe (Demote ending))]
    go Nil = []
    go (s@(Step x) :> xs) = (x, after s) : go xs
```

and then model the relationship between `Nothing` and `Just ending` explicitly, weakening where necessary:

```
type family Meet (a :: Maybe k) (b :: Maybe k) where
    Meet Nothing  b        = b
    Meet a        Nothing  = a
    Meet (Just a) (Just a) = Just a

infixr 5 >:>
(>:>) :: forall before after after' meet a. (Meet after after' ~ meet, SingI meet) => Step a before after -> Steps a after' -> Steps a before
Step x >:> xs = Step x :> xs'
  where
    xs' :: Steps a meet
    xs' = case xs of
        Nil -> Nil
        Step y :> ys -> Step y :> ys
```

This allows us to rewrite `example2` using `Nothing`s to represent endings 
with no constraints:

```
example2 :: Steps Int (Just A)
example2 =
    Step @(Just A) @Nothing 1 >:>
    Step @Nothing  @Nothing 2 >:>
    Step @(Just B) @(Just C) 3 >:>
    nil
```

> ```
> > collapse example2
> (Just A,[(1,Nothing),(2,Just B),(3,Just C)])
> ```

**So now for my question**

Is it possible to remove the need for the explicit `@Nothing` type applications? That is, is there some infrastructure I could add that would make the following mean the same as `example2` above:

```
example2' :: Steps Int (Just A)
example2' =
    Step @(Just A) 1 >:>
    Step 2 >:>
    Step @(Just B) @(Just C) 3 >:>
    nil
```

?

Comment: That's a long question. Before I read it in full: are you sure you're not making this unnecessarily complicated? It seems what you're trying to do is not so much a list (i.e. free monoid) as a free semigroupoid. Wouldn't it help to start from that angle?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I don't think that would change anything -- my problem is with the slack in the middle, not slack at the beginning.

Comment: But perhaps there's a functional dependency `beginning end -> middle`?

Comment: I'm not seeing it. In `example2`, there is slack at the beginning and also between the first and the second step. That is real slack, i.e. that really should be represented as `Nothing`s in the result of `collapse`; propagating the `before` ending of step 3 into step 1 would mean that `collapse` gives an un-true answer.

Comment: @leftroundabout it's a long question because I'm worried it's actually an XY problem.

Comment: This is very Atkey-style; I wonder if you should take a page from McBride. You don't seem to necessarily want those singletons always, or for the endpoints to match exactly. You want some (possibly trivial) relationship between endpoints.

Comment: To be more concrete: I think the right way too not care about a particular endpoint is to not force it to have a singleton.

Comment: @dfeuer: I'm afraid you will have to be more concrete than that, since if there are no singletons, I don't see how to reify those endings in `collapse`.